# Angular2 - Unable to fetch using a 'where' condition in query to a REST API

Tags: rest, curl, parse-platform, angular, parse-server

I am working with Parse Server, and I am trying to fetch data using the REST API in my Angular2 application.

I am trying to fetch data according to a where condition, but I am not able to do so.

This is the code I am using:

```
  constructor(http) {
        var key = new URLSearchParams();
        this.http = http;
        this.disho = null;

        key.set('where', {"estTime":"5min"});
        this.http.get('https://parseapi.example.com/classes/Setto', { where : key }).subscribe(data => {
        this.disho = data.json().results;
        console.log(this.disho);
        });

      }
```

The above code ignore my **where** condition, and returns all the records.

However, the following code returns the right results when executed in terminal via cURL

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: someKey" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: someKey" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'where={"estTime":"5min"}' \
https://parseapi.example.com/classes/Setto
```

Comment: I assume you've ruled out a server-side problem here? if so, open network panel in dev tools and see if the params actually being passed are what you expect

Comment: Could you give us a plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a typo in your code.  Single quotes are missing. You could try the following:

```
key.set('where', '{"estTime":"5min"}');
```

Comment: your solution is 50% of the real solution :D I made it fully working by changing { where : key } to { search : key } in addition to the solution you proposed! Anyway, thank you ! ++1

Answer (score 2):

Change `{ where : key }` to `{ search : key }`

Should work!